# Change extension of a gif file

Tags: visual-studio, image, visual-studio-2005, gif

I need to change the extension a GIF file (changing it in ".gaf") to use it in Visual studio 2005.
Unfortunately the extension does not appear on the file name so when I change the name of the file I get "picture.gaf.gif" even if I see only "picture.gaf" in its name.

Comment: it's not a question for stackoverflow. However, the solution is to check the settings in windows explorer, uncheck the "hide extension for well known extension"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to show the file name extensions. One of the more annoying default-settings in windows!

Copied from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions

**Show or hide file name extensions**

A file name extension is a set of characters added to the end of a file name that determine which program should open it. Follow these steps to choose whether Windows displays these file extensions.

Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.

Click the View tab, and then, under Advanced settings, do one of the following:

To hide file extensions, select the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK.

To display file extensions, clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK.